# What's the source file for the Google Chat app/shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, google-chat

I'm familiar with the .desktop files and have modified them accordingly. I've got a shortcut in my Favorites/more taskbar for a Google Chrome app, Chat. Chrome/Google prompted me to create it and gave it it's own Chat icon. I'd like to auto-launch that at startup. I can launch chrome --app:chat.blah however it doesn't use the icon, it instead launches under the chrome icon as another instance. Not a big deal, but not what I want. Any ideas what this "Chat" shortcut references. I see nothing relevant in the /usr/share/applications/, i.e. only google-chrome and nothing Chat related.

Comment: You will find the .desktop file in your home under .local/share/applications.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Desktop launchers for Google Chrome apps are installed for your user only. Accordingly, the `.desktop` file will be found the `.local/share/applications` folder.

Comment: i think you have a typo. shouln't it be "share" instead of "shar"?

Comment: @totalynotanoob for sure, thank you for the correction!